# Как полученные данные отправлять в точку. В одной точке есть имя и ее координаты , точки я получаю в строке ,строка по типу string!double,double!

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

```
            string pointStr = name!13.6756,14.4732! ...;
            char[] splitchar = { '!', ',' };
            array = pointStr.Split(splitchar);
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                pointName = array[i];
                s = array[i + 1];
                s1 = array[i + 2];
                double.TryParse(s, out LatInicialParking);
                double.TryParse(s1, out LngInicialParking);
                MessageBox.Show(pointName + "\n" + s + "\n" + s1);
                markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay("Маркер");
                gMarker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(LatInicialParking, LngInicialParking), GMarkerGoogleType.red);
                markerOverlay.Markers.Add(gMarker);
                gMarker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;
                gMarker.ToolTipText = string.Format("Паркинг: {0}\n широта: {1}\n долгота: {2}\n", pointName, LatInicialParking, LngInicialParking);
                gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markerOverlay);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шагаем в цикле в три раза дальше:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 2; i = i + 3)
{
  ...
```